# Vaadin calendar

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, vaadin

i tried to play with vaadin calendar a little bit and im facing this problem. I have my calendar i weekly view and when i try to move between weeks ( using arrows in corners ) i get "Communication problem Take note of any unsaved data, and click here or press ESC to continue.Invalid JSON response from server: "
My code looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest)
{
      root = new VerticalLayout();
      Calendar cal = new Calendar("Prominence calendar");
      cal.setWidth("100%");
      cal.setHeight("100%");
      cal.setLocale(Locale.US);
      root.setSizeFull();
      root.addComponent(cal);
      setContent(root);
}
```

I get same error when i for instance add event and move him by drag and drop.
Im using chrome 59.0.3071.115 but it is same on edge/explorer.
I've even tried this code [link](https://demo.vaadin.com/book-examples-vaadin7/book#component.calendar.monthlyview) and i get same error. Can it be something with my app server ( i get it on tomcat as well as on glassfish) ?

Vaadin version is 7.7.5.

Comment: `HTTP Status 404 - /book-examples-vaadin7/book`

Comment: I've edited link in post, try it now, maybe something weird with formating.

Comment: Are you getting erros on the server side (exceptions etc)?

Comment: Nothing, there is no exception on server side.

Comment: If you open chrome developer tools (`F12` or `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `I`), then after accessing your app, can you see any errors logged in the console tab?